# Revisiting the US after 2 months

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

My last visit to the US was for 2 weeks back in August 2013. My point of entry was in San Diego. I plan to revisit for Thanksgiving in November. Will it be an issue that I came back "too soon"?

I am Filipino, using a tourist visa B1/B2 (10 years; multiple entry).

Comment: Spawned my original question into 2. :)

Comment: Are you visiting under ESTA?

Comment: I once entered the US twice in a fortnight, with an ESTA, having returned to Europe in the mean time... I certainly wouldn't recommend it! But there was no problem for me entering when the previous entry hadn't even expired, as I had a suitable reason

Comment: I once visited the US for three days and then after less than a day at home went back in again. No issue. But I am Canadian and a Nexus holder, so I won't say the same applies for everyone.

Comment: I am Filipino. I am not sure what as ESTA is. On my last entry I was given upto Feb 2014.

Comment: @RaizanneRabaya It sounds like you are using a visa to gain entry? If so, it would help if you indicated which visa type it is.

Comment: Tourist visa B1/B2 10years multiple entry @sam

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're visiting, it won't be.  Many people visit more frequently than that (some of my ex-colleagues used to pop over the border from Vancouver every other week).

The main concern from the immigration folk is that you're not 'visiting' - ie you're planning to stay, or are otherwise beating the system.  If you have your travel plans documented, names and addresses of people you're staying with (or hotels), and proof of your intention to depart again (flights etc), everything will usually go fine.

That doesn't mean you won't get questioned - I used to often get asked about the last time I was in the US, but as long as you're honest and open, there should be no problem.